# How do I get Skyrim saves back into save folder from My Documents?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I wanted to start out fresh and never go back into my older saves so I deleted all 400 something saves. Now I've changed my mind so I want to get those deleted saves back. I deleted them from the recycle bin already.

Comment: You can try using an undelete style program. If you haven't used the hard drive too extensively in between you can probably recover them. Unfortunately I don't know one that would recognize the Skyrim save format. When I wanted to recover by 200 hr Oblivion saves I ended up researching and developing a custom program to do it.

Comment: I will assume the main reason why this is receiving all those downvotes is because this isn't a *gaming* question, rather a *how to recover files* question. To add to what was said, it isn't likely you will be able to recover those files, unless you didn't use your computer much since you deleted the files. The reason behind this is because files that are deleted still exist, but in a zombie state, they can be rewritten by the system, and the probability of this happening increases as time passes.

Comment: You may want to ask this question to our good friends at [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/). The [`data-recovery` tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) has some questions that seem relevant to your situation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer-related question *not* specific to video games. It is better suited at [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Related Super User post: [How do I recover or “undelete” files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/q/449550/10259)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to recover files that have been 'permenantly deleted' from the computer.

Most of them involve a [data recovery software](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) of some sort. Out of this list, I have had the best luck with [Recuva by Piriform](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download). Since you are trying to recover files on the hard drive you're likely going to install this program on, I would suggest using the [portable installer instead](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds) and install the program onto a USB Flash Drive. This will prevent you accidentally writing over the now empty space where your files were.

As far as running the software is concerned, you simply run the .exe, point it at the HDD you wish to scan for deleted files and let it do its thing.

If you end up getting your save files back, great! If not, you can [enjoy picturing this happening when you create your new character!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJD4b.jpg)

Comment: There are actually methods to recover files you deleted. You just have to hope the OS didn't overwrite their places in the meantime.

Comment: Fine... I'll update my answer!

Comment: I actually tried using Recuva and it only showed 5 files that werent any saves.

Comment: You never mentioned exactly how long ago you deleted the files, that could be a factor in why you can't recover them.

Comment: It was at least 1 week ago or a bit lower than a week.

Comment: A week is a long time, especially if you have been using the computer. If you have backups, you could possibly restore from those.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows Backup or Shadow Copies turned on, you might be able to get the files back from previous versions. Right-click the folder where the saves were, click *Properties*, then look in the *Previous Versions* tab. You might be able to open a previous version of the folder and recover the files from inside it.

This assumes you are using a recent version Windows, of course.

Comment: I have Windows 8, and it says it won't work on it. I have tried file history and it only shows dates from today. Is there a way to make system restore effect documents?

Comment: @KhangMai Looks like this feature has changed in Windows 8, and is now called *Windows File History*. Here's how to set it up for the future: http://lifehacker.com/5958865/how-to-use-windows-8s-new-file-history-backup-aka-time-machine-for-windows